# linux-headers-4.4.0-120 error

Tags: apt, software-center

dear all im getting this error while upgrading or installing any software

```
error:E: The package linux-headers-4.4.0-120 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Comment: There is [no such official package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=linux-headers-4.4.0-120&searchon=names). How did you get it? Are you running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Comment: yes iam running ubuntu 16.04 lts

Comment: You missed the question of "How did you get it?" meaning how did you get that kernel when it is not an official package?

Comment: i dont know i have upgraded my pc past 3 days after which this error is coming.

Comment: Same error still coming.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove this package and reinstall current (119) one:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.4.0-120
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic
```

And if you have enabled *xenial-proposed*, please disable them in
*Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`), *Developer Options* tab, uncheck *Pre-released updates (xenial-proposed)*.

Comment: same error still coming.